# How to get the mean(average) for elements of user input array?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

This may be a dumb question, but I'm very new to JavaScript and can't for the life of me figure out how to get the mean(average) of user inputted array elements. Here's the code I wrote so far where the user is prompted to enter the number of elements in the array and loops back and prompts that many times to enter the elements. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Title</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var nums = new Array();
    var N = prompt("How many numbers would you like to enter? ");
    N = parseInt(N);
    var i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i <= N - 1; i++)
    {
        nums[i] = prompt("Enter your numbers: ");
        document.write("Number you chose: " + nums[i] + "<br />");
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `var sum = 0;` before the loop, `sum += Number(nums[i])` inside the loop (after the line with the prompt), and `var average = sum / N;` after the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a summation var `s` to add value of inputs and calculate the average at end using this formula `average = s / N`:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    var nums = new Array();
    var N = prompt("How many numbers would you like to enter? ");
    N = parseInt(N);
    var i = 0, s = 0;
    for(i = 0; i <= N - 1; i++)
    {
        nums[i] = parseInt(prompt("Enter your numbers: "));
        s += nums[i];
        document.write("Number you chose: " + nums[i] + "<br />");
    }
    var ave = s / N;
    document.write("Average: " + ave + "<br />");
</script>
```

Also if you don't need those input numbers, you can remove the `nums` array and use a simple var instead of it:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
 var nums = new Array();
 var N = prompt("How many numbers would you like to enter? ");
 N = parseInt(N);
 var i = 0, s = 0;
 for(i = 0; i <= N - 1; i++)
 {
  var x = parseInt(prompt("Enter your numbers: "));
  s += x;
  document.write("Number you chose: " + x + "<br />");
 }
 var ave = s / N;
 document.write("Average: " + ave + "<br />");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
        var nums = new Array();
        var N = prompt("How many numbers would you like to enter? ");
        N = parseInt(N);
        var i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i <= N - 1; i++) {
            // convert string to integer
            nums[i] = parseInt(prompt("Enter your numbers: "));
            document.write("Number you chose: " + nums[i] + "<br />");
        }

        var sum = nums.reduce(function(prev, cur) {
            return prev + cur;
        }, 0);

        var avg = sum / N;
        console.log(avg);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this...

```
<title>
  Title</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function getSum(total, num) {
    return total + num;
  }

  var nums = new Array();
  var N = prompt("How many numbers would you like to enter? ");
  N = parseInt(N);
  var i = 0;

  for (i = 0; i <= N - 1; i++) {
    nums[i] = parseInt(prompt("Enter your numbers: "));
    document.write("Number you chose: " + nums[i] + "<br />");

  }
   document.write("Avg. of entered numbers = " + (nums.reduce(getSum)) / nums.length);

</script>

<body>
</body>
```

Check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/45ab1812/1/

Comment: This gives a sum of entered numbers not an average.

Comment: Oops . Thanks . Updated my answer and fiddle

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are able to define `var i = 0` in your for loop, and `i <= N - 1` is the same as `i < N`. The more simple way to write your loop would be.. `for(var i = 0; i < N; i++)` (also removing the `var N = 0;` from above).

Now it's not necessary to put the user's numbers into an array to get the average of them. All you need for the average is the sum of numbers and the amount of numbers.

Another cool thing about Javascript is that it freely converts the variable you are using into the type of variable that is appropriate for the context being used. This means that `N = parseInt(N);` is not necessary in your case, because it can only be treated as an integer in the loop.

If you take both of the above notes into consideration, you could use one of the following codes.

**Solution 1: No array, just keeping the sum and amount of numbers**

```
//Prompt the user how many numbers they would like to enter
var N = prompt("How many numbers would you like to enter? ");

//Set sum to 0, which gives us a base to add each number to it.
var sum = 0;  

//Complete this loop the same amount of times as the user entered in the prompt
for (var i = 0; i < N; i++ ) {

    //Add the users response to the sum of responses
    sum += parseInt(prompt("Enter your numbers: "));
}

//Write into the document the sum of 
document.write( "Avg. of entered numbers = " + sum / N);
```

However if you actually want to use an array as your question states, you could use the following code.

**Solution 2: An array, while keeping track of the sum**

```
//Prompt the user how many numbers they would like to enter
var N = prompt("How many numbers would you like to enter? ");

//Create an empty array to push elements to it
var nums = new Array();

//Set sum to 0, which gives us a base to add each number to it.
var sum = 0;  

//Complete this loop the same amount of times as the user entered in the prompt
for (var i = 0; i < N; i++ ) {

    //Get the users response to a variable
    var response = parseInt(prompt("Enter your numbers: "));

    //Add that variable to the sum
    sum += response;

    //And also push that variable to the array
    nums.push(response);
}

//Write into the document the sum of the document
document.write( "Avg. of entered numbers = " + sum / nums.length);
```

If you noticed there we used `nums.length` instead of `N`. If you have a situation where you are unsure how many numbers the user will type in you could use the length of the array to see how many were entered.

Now here is an even simpler way you can do it while using arrays without keeping track of the sum of the array in the for loop. This takes advantage of the reduce function that many other answers have used.

**Solution 3: Just an array!**

```
//Prompt the user how many numbers they would like to enter
var N = prompt("How many numbers would you like to enter? ");

//Create an empty array to push elements to it
var nums = new Array();

//Complete this loop the same amount of times as the user entered in the prompt
for (var i = 0; i < N; i++) {

  //Push users response to the original array
  nums.push(parseInt(prompt("Enter your numbers: ")));

}

//Use the reduce function to get the sum of the array, and then divide it by the amount of elements in the array.
document.write( "Avg. of entered numddbers = " + (nums.reduce((a, b) => a + b) / nums.length));
```